# Get field values from given id in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to develop a website with asp.net mvc and EF6 where I can send message from the gsm modem according to the number given in SQL Server table. So far I've managed to get the id and pass it as a parameter but I can't figure it out how to get the other fields according to the passed id.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SendSms(int RentId=0)
{
        ClientBill BillTable = rentdb.ClientBills.Find(RentId);
        var GetName = rentdb.ClientBills.Where(a => a.fullname.Equals(BillTable.fullname)).FirstOrDefault();
        var GetNumber = rentdb.ClientBills.Where(a => a.phone.Equals(BillTable.phone)).FirstOrDefault();

        try
        {
            SP.PortName = "COM4";
            SP.Open();
            string ph_no;
            ph_no = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + GetNumber + char.ConvertFromUtf32(34);
            SP.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(13));
            SP.Write("AT+CMGS=" + ph_no + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(13));
            SP.Write(GetName + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(13));
            SP.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("SmsView");
}
```

Getting the id like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.RentCollection)
{
    <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="@Url.Action("SendSms", "Home", new{ RentId=item.serial })"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a></td>
}
```

I can't get it done by what I've given here. How can I get the fields of the corresponding id? Need help badly. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what does "the other fields" means in your question

Comment: other fields mean the `fullname` & `phone` field.

Comment: from what i see the `GetNumber` and `GetName ` are not simple string or char[] variables, i don't think the part `ph_no = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + GetNumber + char.ConvertFromUtf32(34)` will even compile. if you just need to form a string, you need to do `ph_no = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + GetNumber.phone+ char.ConvertFromUtf32(34)`

Comment: I was missing this. Silly me. If you could provide your solution as an answer then I could vote it for you. :)

Comment: It's probably just because you're still working on the code, but even during initial development it's still a bad idea to catch `Exception`, if for no other reason than you just might forget to change it to something more specific later. Here, you have a very real possibility of throwing null reference exceptions because you're not checking that `GetName` and `GetNumber` actually have a value. You don't want that being caught by the code that should be catching exceptions on your COM interface.